# Command-line arguments

Tags: c++, arguments, program-entry-point, argv, argc

I am aware that the `main` function can take two arguments: `int argc` and `char* argv[]`. This is well documented. However the `main` function can also take a third argument. Does anyone one know what this argument is?

Comment: In C, that would be `char** envp`, the environment variables.

Comment: @Cicada it is not POSIX (or ANSI C as far as I can remember).

Comment: @juanchopanza It's not POSIX indeed but that is beyond OP's question.

Comment: @Cicada you're right. I just wanted to stress that it is very unportable.

Answer (score 3):

It's the environment variables, and have the same type as the normal `argv`. It's not part of the C++ standard though, but may still work on some systems.

It's from older UNIX systems, where the environment variables often was passed like this.

Comment: envp is always passed, at least on unix (and it works today too due to historical and backward-compatible reasons)

Comment: Even if it didn't pass to C++, you could always just write your entry points in C and have it call your C++ program, right?

Comment: @Bingo The `main` function in both C and C++ should be called the same by the run-time system. So it's usable in both C and C++, but unportable outside the UNIX world.

Comment: Perhaps for elaboration. Does the programmer need an int envc as an equivelent for argc, so that the programmmer can see how many envrironment variables are passed to the program. Or is char env[] sentinalled with a NULL pointer?

Comment: @hetepeperfan There's no `envc`, but the array is terminated by a `NULL` just like `argv`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `main` may have also a forth argument on Mac OS, of the form `char **apple`, "containing arbitrary OS-supplied information". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#C_and_C.2B.2B for details.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two forms of `main` which are required to be
supported, and which are portable to all platforms.  But an
implementation can add any additional forms it wants: `int main(
double )` would be legal, for example (although I've never heard
of an implementation which uses it), as would `int main( char
const* arg0... )`.  In practice, "classical" Unix would support
`int main( int argc, char** argv, char** environ )`; this is
*not* required by Posix, and presumably, there are some Unix
which don't support it.  Outside of the Unix world, many early
C implementations tried to look like Unix, and so may also
support this (today more for reasons of backwards compatibility
than to look like Unix).

It's not something you can count on, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `char *env[]`, it need not be named like this, though, in order to pass a different set of environment-variables. You can change the environment the particular process is executing in.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function) article, there is an explanation.